# mouseover and mouseout events not firing using pure js

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseover, mouseout

I have a setup where i am trying to assign a `mouseover` and `mouseout` event on a `div`, but they dont appear to be firing. Right now i just have it trying to `console.log`the `mouseout` event and add classes to the `body` as well for the `mouseover` event.

I have trying using `.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){})` instead of `.onmouseover` to no avail. I have also tried `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` but these are IE only events.

I need to use pure Javascript rather than any 3rd party library, this also needs to work in IE8+.

HTML

```
<div class="of_expandable" data-channel="2935725596001" data-muted="1" data-skin="dark"></div>
```

JS

```
/*
    for each expandable element this function:
    - parses the data attributes for handing to the embeds
    - styles the expandable div
    - binds the hover event to the div
*/
function processExpandable (elm, index){
    elm.className += " processed";
    elm.id = exp_ns + "_expandable_" + index;

    // option parsing
    var options = {};
    options.skin = elm.getAttribute("data-skin");
    if(!options.skin){
        options.skin = 'light';
    }

    // styling
    elm.style.width = "300px";
    elm.style.height = "250px";
    elm.style.position = "relative";
    elm.style.backgroundColor = "#000";

    // add events to elm
    elm.onmouseover = function (){
        launchModal(elm, options.skin);
    };
    elm.onmouseout = function (){
        console.log('mouseout');
    };
}

/*
    opens the modal and populates
*/
function launchModal (elm, skin){
    console.log('entered');
    document.body.className += " " + exp_ns + "_modal_open modal_skin_" + skin;
}

/*
    closes the modal and clears
*/
function closeModal (){
    // TODO: clear data from modal
    var pattern = "/\b" + exp_ns + "_modal_open\b/";
    document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(pattern,'');
    var pattern = "/\bmodal_skin_light\b/";
    document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(pattern,'');
    var pattern = "/\bmodal_skin_dark\b/";
    document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(pattern,'');
}


/*
    adds the modal element waiting to be triggered by the expandables
    - adds background
    - adds modal box
*/
function addModal (){
    var modalHTML = '<div id="' + exp_ns + '_modal" class="exp_modal"></div><div id="' + exp_ns + '_modal_back" class="exp_modal_back"></div>';
    document.body.innerHTML += modalHTML;
}


/*
    tests if an element has a class
*/
function hasClass(elm, cls) {
    return (' ' + elm.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}
var exp_ns = "of"
  , expandables = getElementsByClassName(exp_ns + '_expandable')
  , hoverTimer
  , hoverPause = 1000;

if(expandables.length > 0){
    for (var i = 0; i < expandables.length; i++){
        if(!hasClass(expandables[i], "processed")){
            // make sure we arent adding twice from a double include
            processExpandable(expandables[i], i);   
        }
    }
    // make sure we arent adding twice from a double include
    var modal = document.getElementById(exp_ns + '_overlay');
    if(!modal){
        addModal();
    }
}else{
    console.log('warning: no expandable elements found');
}
```

here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfh3N/)

**SOLUTION UPDATE:**

So it appears that the reason this was breaking was because of the way that I was inserting the modal elements using `document.body.innerHTML +=` . Which I think must read all the innerHTML with the newly appended content. As a better solution I used this:

```
function addModal (){
    var modalBack = document.createElement("div");
        modalBack.setAttribute("class", "exp_modal_back");
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(modalBack);
    var modalCont = document.createElement("div");
        modalCont.setAttribute("class", "exp_modal");
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(modalCont);
}
```

updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfh3N/4/)

Comment: Thank you, I also had a similar, stumping issue because I was doing an `.innerHTML += ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with how you are using the event handlers. The problem is being caused by the "addModal" function called after the "processExpandable" function. I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish so I can't help you there, but it is a start.

Also, I think you have a problem in the "launchModal" function. Do you really want to keep adding and adding values to the class attribute of the body?

Comment: wow that's so weird that that function wasnt throwing an error, yet it was causing the problem. awesome pickup. The launchModal function is going to be forcing a modal to open which will cover the `div`.. but i will add code so it only triggers once

Comment: When you append to the innerHTML of an element (as is done in `addModal`), all child elements are destroyed and recreated, and the event handlers are not automatically reattached.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way :

```
 <div style=" height: 200px; width:200px; background-color: black;" 
       onmouseover="displayElement('myDiv');"
       onmouseout="hideElement('myDiv');">
       <div id="myDiv" class="of_expandable" data-channel="2935725596001" data-muted="1" data-skin="dark" style="width:100%; height:100%;display: none; background-color:green;">Content</div>
</div>
```

here is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/huyofage/2/edit) to show you

Comment: as much as possible id like to not have inline js. i also need to trigger functions in an external file rather than style changes, which this seems not to like doing. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I edited my post and changed it to call specific functions, enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks, this works, but it looks like my problem was elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling over this question, maybe first check if you hadn't given your desired element `pointer-events: none;` in css first, as i did.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).